# Want to use expl3 seq variable as an "array" data structure

Tags: expl3, seq

The question is: `expl3` provides for indexing positions in a `seq` variable for reading items, is there a way to write to an indexed position? I noticed the question asked by @XZS on July 24, 15 too late, so I ask for an update on the plans of adding an `\array` function to interface3 (see comment by @Christian Hupfer)

```
\documentclass{article}
%  RN. 24/10/2016
%  DESCRIPTION: want to use _seq variable as an "array" data structure and be able 
% to not only get (read) but also set (write to) items in indexed positions. Can 
% be achieved with "gets" and "puts" or "pops" and "pushes" of course, but this will be 
% cumbersome and slow. Worse still, similar holds for tokenlist variables.  
\usepackage{xparse} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_rn_Array_seq
\int_new:N \l_rn_Count_int
\int_new:N \l_rn_index_int
\tl_new:N \l_rn_aux_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\myArray{O{1}O{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m}}
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \g_rn_Array_seq {,}{#2}  
    \int_set:Nn \l_rn_Count_int {\seq_count:N \g_rn_Array_seq}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_aux_tl {\seq_item:Nn \g_rn_Array_seq{#1}}
    item~#1~in~(\seq_use:Nn \g_rn_Array_seq {,~}) :~\textbf{\l_rn_aux_tl} 
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
1. \verb+\myArray+\\    
\myArray

2. \verb+\myArray[6]+\\ 
\myArray[6]

3. \verb+\myArray[4][a,sdf,qarg,12354m145,rg,ra,h]+\\   
\myArray[4][a,sdf,qarg,12354m145,rg,ra,h]

\end{document}\documentclass{minimal}
```

Comment: I suggest you look at the `listofitems` package.  It might be already able to do what you are asking, I think.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes. Just looked at it, most likely provides the functionality, however I am currently on a mission, which is: I want to do things as described in the latex3 documents: interface3, expl3, xparse, l3regex, l3str and l3sort (have I missed any?) to the point why I even regard expression like`\def...`as undesirable calligraphy that belongs behind the scenes. I am currently getting my indexed writing functionality from a work-around, which is OK on the small scale but too slow for serious applications.

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples .... (And using it twice doesn't really help ...)

Comment: `xfrac`, `xtemplate`, `xgalley`, `xcoffins`. (Ignoring contrib.) ?

Comment: @cfr very careless of me to leave them out. Not sure what you mean by `minimal`, nor where it's been used twice.

Comment: The minimal class is used in the first line and quoted in the last (I say quoted, as everything after `\end{document} ` us obviously ignored). In any case minimal should not be used in examples like this as there are many things it does not define and thus is not suitable for examples. I don't even know what the minimal class is good for.

Comment: @cfr @daleif Point taken, I shall use `article` from here on.  The second `minimal` slipped in by mistake. I am usually having problems pasting my code into the window and ended up with it twice, then missed that first line when deleting the second copy.

Comment: May be your are looking more for `prop` rather than `seq`?

Comment: Did you try the `prop` approach? Or what exactly are you requiring in addition?